# std::ifstream and reading files

Tags: c++, ifstream

So I've been stuck with a problem for a while now and I can't figure out why it's not working. It is probably something really stupid that I've forgotten about but I'm having a huge problem reading from a file located in my project.

I'm trying to use "res/dir/file.txt" as a filepath but it wont work. I've also tried to move the file for "file.txt" filepath, but nothing. I've been moving the file around all over the project to see if can reach it from somewhere but with no success. The working directory is $(ProjectDir)

```
streamFile("res/dir/file.txt");
```

My function looks something like this and I'm not able to enter the while loop with (getline(stream, line)) which is my major indicator to the problem:

```
void streamFile(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);
    std::string line;
    while (getline(stream, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#Example") != std::string::npos)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }   
    return;
}
```

I feel really stupid atm because I know that I've done this before and never had a similar problem. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "it wont work"? What exactly is the problem? Is the file not found? Does the function not fire? What?

Comment: Try to use an absolute file path, e.g. `c:/mydocs/res/dir/file.txt` or `/Users/thatsme/docs/file.txt`

Comment: The function runs fine except that It won't enter the while loop. I assume this is because I can't find the file I'm looking for. I'm out of ideas of why I can't get access to it or find it in my solution with the filepath.

Comment: @EmilGustafsson "_I assume this is because <...>_" Why are you _assuming_? Check whether file is opened, and you will _know_.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Well it's not open. Assuming I've used "if (stream.is_open())" correctly.

Comment: Do you know what a relative path and current working directory are? Have you checked the error code (`cout << strerror(errno)`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. I tried it out this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
  std::ifstream stream("./res/dir/test.txt");
  std::cout << (stream.is_open() ? "file successfully opened" : "file could not be opened") << std::endl;
  std::string line;
  while (getline(stream, line))
  {
    std::cout << "line read: " << line << std::endl;
    if (line.find("my") != std::string::npos)
    {
      std::cout << "\t ... found magic word" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "\t ... no magic word in this line" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

**./res/dir/test.txt**

```
hello world
my name is john doe
how are you?
```

The output is as expected:

```
file successfully opened
line read: hello world
     ... no magic word in this line
line read: my name is john doe
     ... found magic word
line read: how are you?
     ... no magic word in this line
```

Comment: I know that the function should work fine but for some reason I can't reach the file in my solution. I've tried different files, used the full file path but I can't figure out why it won't read.

Comment: Could you post your folder-structure? This program works perfectly fine, when I create a directory `./res/dir` next to the binary and move the textfile into that. Please see here: [how to provide a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: /solution/project/res/dir/file.txt so res is in the same folder as src.

Comment: and where is the binary? the path you specify is relative to the binary. So is it in `/solution/project` or somewhere like `/solution/project/bin`?!

Comment: solution/bin/Debug-windows-x86_64/ProjectName/  I'm not sure if it is what you asked for, but that is the output directory.

Comment: there you go. then try to open the file with the relative path: `../../../res/dir/file.txt`. In your final application you need to deploy that folder into the installation-directory

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not able to open the file. I also tried to put the file directly in the folder an access it.

Comment: You need to consider your current 'working directory' (`pwd`). If you *are* in `c:/user/john/project/bin` and call `./myProgram.exe`, then you need the file to be in `c:/user/john/project/bin/res/dir/file.txt`. If you are in `c:/user/john/project` and call `./bin/myProgram.exe`, then the file needs to be in `c:/user/john/project/res/dir/file.txt`. So I guess you need to understand, how your IDE works, and what your working-dir is. Maybe try to **create** a file instead and see where it ends up.

Comment: @EmilGustafsson The simple way to solve this is to change your code to **write** a file using the same path. Then look to see where that new file is. That will tell you where you need to put the file for reading.

Comment: Thanks for the tip it solved my problem. I created a file and located it inside another project folder inside of the solution.